# Magento Cash on Delivery success page throwing error after upgarding to 1.9.2

Tags: magento, checkout, fatal-error

After upgrading to magento 1.9.2 and also updating the theme, when I was checking the payment option after i selected the cashondelivery payment option and clicked on place an order got a message that "Your order has been received.
Thank you for your purchase!" but below that page I got this error -
Fatal error: Call to a member function loadByIncrementId() on a non-object in /public_html/app/design/frontend/theme/default/template/checkout/success.phtml on line 87

Could someone please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: The last order was not correctly placed, so I would suggest to check the database. Also, try to debug the success.phtml and check last order object and provide more information.

Comment: Thank for your answer kamal. I debugged success.phtml and found that the google conversion tracking code was causing the error. I removed it and the error is not coming up anymore.

Comment: Glad to hear. Please close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I debugged success.phtml and found that the google conversion tracking code was causing the error. I removed it and the error is not coming up anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I debugged checkout/success.phtml and found that the some useless code for send order mail which not found helper class so I found fatal error. I removed it and the error is not coming up anymore.